# how to restrict access to directory so I can run php scripts from browser

Tags: php, restrict

First post, be gentle :) ... I have been doing searches on this site as well as others and realize I may be in over my head.

Here is the situation:

1) I have a website running on BlueHost (linux OS, I think is running Apache) that is open for general access

2) I have a set of php scripts on the website that I would like to limit the access to only one user via some sort of login through a webbrowser.

3) I have put the scripts in a directory under /home/public_html.  I did not know how to access the files with a web browser above that level (like in /home)

4) These scripts do not access any other part of the website nor does any other part of the website access the scripts.

Here is what I tried:

1) Using cpanel to change the permissions on the directory. Result was a 404 when I try to access the scripts with a browser.

2) .htaccess/.htpasswd for the folder in question (found some instructions here and on the web).  Didn't seem to force asking for a password so I probably did something wrong

I know this is vague but I will ask it anyway...  Given my situation, is there a preferred approach I can research?  For example, having the php code ask the user for a password, somehow accessing the scripts from the server side, etc.

Thanks for your patience and help

Comment: If you're really sure it's always going to be one user only, you can probably use cpanel to password-protect that one directory (most likely using .htaccess / .htpasswd...). However, if you will have more users or different user levels in the future, you'd better build it into the php, just start every php file with an include to your authentication module.

Answer (score 3):

Do the following in the folder where the php scripts reside,

1. Create a .htaccess file in your text editor. Add the following data and save the file as .htaccess. The leading dot is important.

`AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Secret Files"
Require valid-user`

2. Edit the path/to/.htpasswd to match the folder where your php scripts reside. You can also make the AuthName anything you want. This is the name the user sees when the password prompt appears.
3. Copy that file to the folder where your php scripts reside.
4. Now create the actual password file. The format looks like this:

   `username:encryptedPassword`
5. You can create a username/encrypted pair by using the free tool here:

   http://www.web2generators.com/apache/htpasswd_generator

Just enter the username and the unencrypted password you want to assign the user. You may also want to assign yourself one so you can also access the files from your browser.

There are other ways to create the username and password, but this will get you up and running. You can always Google how to do it from cpanel and the command line if you prefer.

6. Click the generate link and copy the resulting code.
7. Open a new file in your text editor and paste the results.
8. Save it as .htpasswd
9. Copy that file to the folder where your php scripts and the .htaccess file reside.
10. Access the php script from your browser. You should be prompted to enter a user name and password before the script will execute.

Comment: Thank you Len_D and jeoreon!  I will try and report back.

Comment: the directory I *think* should be password protected is called "parent" which contains directories "child1" and "child2".  "child1" contains the main scripts but also calls on files inside of "child2".  My thinking is to have the .htaccess and .htpassword at the "parent" level and nothing at the "child1" or "child2" levels.  Does that sound correct?

Comment: I added a .htaccess and .htpasswd in both the "child1" and "child2" directories.  After clearing the cache on the server and using Chrome's "incognito mode" I still get a 404 error trying to access the script located in "child1"   :(

Comment: You want to protect the folder where the index.php or whatever the entry script resides. Unprotect child1 and see if your problem goes away. .htpasswd should not be doing anything that would generate a 404, so you might need to look elsewhere.

Comment: yes, unprotecting child1 (which has my script) allows it to work.  protecting the child1 folder gives the 404.  I'll try disabling a security plugin to check if that is influencing things.

Comment: I deactivated all the plugins and still no luck :(

Comment: Define "no luck? Are oyu not getting the password prompt, or are you getting the 404 after you complete the login?

Comment: sorry for the lack of information.  By no luck I mean no password prompt and only a 404 page

Comment: you need to make sure you have your paths set right in .htaccess and .htpassswd.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to make it work (although not why it didn't work).

Len_D's method was absolutely correct.  For some reason I had to make a subdomain out of "parent" and then it all worked out.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Rather than posting an answer to your own question stating that one of the other answers was correct, but with some minor changes, instead mark that answer as correct and put your changes as a comment to that answer. The author will be notified and should update their answer to reflect the changes. Alternatively, you can Suggest and Edit to the correct answer to provide all needed steps.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Please select my answer so the issue will be marked closed.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, You can create a username/encrypted pair by using the free tool [htpasswd generator](http://wtools.io/generate/htpasswd)