# How to restrict access to directory on server, using PHP logic?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a directory on my server that I want the general public to not have access to. (Nothing. No access to php files, images, anything.)

But I want to allow certain users to access this restricted area based on a boolean value in my php.

Is there any way to use PHP to determine whether or not a user can access a directory, similar to the using an htaccess file but with more customized logic?

Comment: use htpasswd http auth, this link is a good resource http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/ . You place a .htpasswd file in the directory you want to be protected and it will be accessed using only username/password . Read this one too http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: @MuhammedM. This isn't what I was asking for, unfortunately.

Comment: Provide more deatail, using examples.

Comment: Please provide more detail as to what you are trying to do *and what you have tried.* Right now, this question is much too broad and is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way is to redirect restricted users to your homepage.

```
<?php
   header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com' ) ;
   exit;
?>
```

You can allow access to specific users by setting Boolean value in your DB.

Below solution will work based on your file storage location.

```
$file = '/file.png'; // set your file location
$userAccess = false;
if (file_exists($file) && $userAccess) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=your_file.png');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
}
```

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289200/how-to-restrict-access-to-directory-so-i-can-run-php-scripts-from-browser) also.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: But this doesn't restrict the content of a directory. Just the files I place this in.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found an answer elsewhere and it involves setting up a PHP file as a sort of proxy in conjunction with htaccess - http://simpletek.raivo.id.lv/restrict-server-files-access-based-on-php-logic/

Comment: Its not a proxy or anything its a simple mod_rewrite technique. By the way solution there is not secured at all, i hope u dont listen to that: guy suggests adding a parameter to file url, just to get it downloaded securily. Bad practice, very bad. Anyone who knows that extra "secure" string, can get your content.